# Price feed to add new tokens to assets list

Tags: gnosis-safe

We use a Safe Multisig as a fees receiver for some of our strategies.

These fees tokens are captured by the Safe UI, but unfortunately do not show their $ value.

I would like to understand which price feed Safe uses and fix this.

Safe address `eth:0xFb3bD022D5DAcF95eE28a6B07825D4Ff9C5b3814`

Fees token address example `0xb86264c21418aA75F7c337B1821CcB4Ff4d57673`

Answer (score 0):

This article describes which price oracles are used in Ethereum (Mainnet): https://help.gnosis-safe.io/en/articles/4634540-how-is-the-fiat-value-of-assets-calculated

Comment: Thanks, this helps. 

I see the following: `In case the above checks fail, there is a custom implementation to used to get prices specifically for LP tokens [...]`. Can you please point me to the repo of these custom implementations so that I can understand what should be done on our side to complete the listing?